# Elastic beanstalk- Force apache to cache with .ebextensions config file (ubuntu)

Tags: apache, caching, amazon-web-services, gzip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there any way to force apache to cache images/scripts/css files with the use of .ebextensions config files?

Im looking for an answer that doesnt use SSH.